# Swift Dictionary using subset of Array of Struct

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from an array of struct using grouping but I am not having much luck (I found a way iterating over every record but was hoping for a more elegant solution)...

```
var eventRecords =  [EventRecord]()
```

and the structure looks like this (used to store records in CloudKit)

```
public struct EventRecord {
    public var evDate: Date
    public var evType: Int
    public var evMainTxt: String
    public var evNote: String?
    public var evVal1: Int?
    public var evVal2: Int?
}
```

what I am hoping to accomplish is a dictionary where the **key is evType** and the **value is [evMainTxt]**. the dict is defined as

```
var suggestionsDict = [Int: [String]]()
```

I started with `Dictionary(grouping: eventRecords, by: {$0.evType})` but I am strugling with the `.map` portion of this statement `Dictionary(grouping: eventRecords, by: {$0.evType}).map` since I only want a subset of the EventRecord struct. Can it be done short of iterating over all the records? Since I am new to this, any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `reduce(into:)` so you can map and group in one step

```
let suggestionsDict = eventRecords.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1.evType, default: []].append($1.evMainTxt)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , i haven't come across the `reduce` function before... pretty neat and worked like a charm

Comment: @Sami you were pretty close `Dictionary(grouping: eventRecords, by: \.evType)
    .mapValues { $0.map(\.evMainTxt) }}`

Comment: thank you @leo , had to think about that solution for a little :) but pretty powerful combination of `map` and `mapvalue`